# Set max column value as sequence start value with liquibase tags

Tags: sql, liquibase

I wonder if it possible to get maximum column value from a certain table and set it as start sequence value with no pure sql. The following code doesn't work:

```
   <property name="maxId" value="(select max(id)+1 from some_table)" dbms="h2,mysql,postgres"/>
   <changeSet author="author (generated)" id="1447943899053-1">
      <createSequence sequenceName="id_seq" startValue="${maxId}" incrementBy="1"/>
   </changeSet>
```

Got an error:

```
Caused by: liquibase.parser.core.ParsedNodeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${m"
```

I've tried it with no parentheses around `select ...` etc. with the same result.
So it's not possible to use computed value as start sequence value?

Comment: For Postgres the only thing I can think of is to create the sequence, then use a `<sql>` tag to run `select setval('id_seq', (select max(id)+1 from some_table));`.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your configuration file? In what environment are you using liquibase?

Comment: Norbert, Java8, Spring-boot 1.2.6, Liquibase 3.4.1, Postgres (9.3-1102-jdbc41) for execution and H2 for tests.

Comment: I tried the following:
`<changeSet author="dfche" id="1448634241199-1">
      <createSequence sequenceName="user_id_seq" startValue="1" incrementBy="1"/>
   </changeSet>
   <changeSet author="dfche" id="1448634241199-2">
      <sql dbms="postgres">alter sequence user_id_seq restart with 333</sql>
      <sql dbms="h2">alter sequence user_id_seq restart with (select max(id)+1 from jhi_user)</sql>
   </changeSet>`
H2 works OK. For Postgres, "select setval(...)" doesn't work, neither does "alter sequence ... restart with ...".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name your solution was right in general, you may post it as an answer. All my problems were because of misspelled db name in dbms tag. I finally implemented the sequence setting like this:
`<sql dbms="postgresql">select setval('user_id_seq', max(id)+1) from jhi_user</sql>
      <sql dbms="h2">alter sequence user_id_seq restart with (select max(id)+1 from jhi_user)</sql>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, such a solution worked for me:

```
<changeSet author="dfche" id="1448634241199-1"> 
  <createSequence sequenceName="user_id_seq" startValue="1" incrementBy="1"/> 
</changeSet> 
<changeSet author="dfche" id="1448634241199-2">
  <sql dbms="postgresql">select setval('user_id_seq', max(id)+1) from jhi_user</sql> 
  <sql dbms="h2">alter sequence user_id_seq restart with (select max(id)+1 from jhi_user)</sql>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

For postgres correct sql dbms sentence is:

```
<sql dbms="postgresql">select setval('some_table_id_seq', (select max(id)+1 from some_table), false)</sql>
```