# How to create sequence with an existing starting value in liquibase

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

I have an existing sequence in my postgres database which is used for all my tables.
I need to migrate one table to use another (new) sequence which will be used for that table.
Thing is, the new sequence should start from the current value of the existing sequence.

For that matter I wanted to use the following code:

```
<changeSet id="Add new sequence for BOOKS tables" author="app">
    <createSequence sequenceName="SEQUENCE_BOOKS_UID" incrementBy="50" cacheSize="1" maxValue="9223372036854775807" startValue="select nextval('SEQ')"/>
</changeSet>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

I saw [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888587/set-max-column-value-as-sequence-start-value-with-liquibase-tags) - but I wanted to know if there is another way around

Comment: I think using a `<sql>` tag with a `setval()` (as described in the workaround) is the only way you can do that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Thanks. It works for me - but if I will find another way around I will post it here